# AngularJS style set background

Tags: css, angularjs, background

I have the following Javascript objects:

[image: My Objects look like this]

There are two properties of this objects: **pesonalColor** and **personRoleColor**
I have a flag called **vm.colorSwitch** with which I will switch the color of the span below. With **personalColor** it works fine but I don't know how to bring in personRoleColor to switch between the colors.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
<span ng-repeat="myObject in myObjects" style="width:{{myObject.percentage}}%; background:{{myObject.personalColor}}" class="progress-bar" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) allows programatic use of the style attribute.

```
<span ng-style="{
    background: vm.colorSwitch ? myObject.personalColor : myObject.personRoleColor, 
    width: myObject.percentage + '%'
}" ...></span>
```